# Nesting an IF function in a SUMIF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas, sumifs, array-formulas

I have a list of sales people, but only a portion of their sales can count in the sum total.  Example:

```
SP    Sales
John   600
Jane   200
John    50
Mike   150
```

`=SUMIF(SP,"John",Sales)` will give me the total of all `John`'s sales. 
But only up to 125 of each of John's sales can count in this total.  So the result should be 175.

I tried: `=IF(sales,>=125,"125"+SUMIF(SP,"John",Sales))` but it didn't work.

What *do* I require for it to work?

Comment: Did you mean the result should be 125? If not, where does the extra 50 come from? Also, is the maximum universal (i.e., everyone is maxed out at 125), or is it unique to the person?

Comment: Also, what behavior are you trying to get from adding the string `"125"` to the `SUMIF` result, rather than just the number 125?

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"John",B:B,"<"&125)+125*COUNTIFS(A:A,"John",B:B,">=125")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an array formula like this:

`{=SUM(--(A2:A5="John") * IF(B2:B5>125,125,B2:B5))}`